# Synchronize executable files based on same path and filename

Tags: shell, synchronization, executable

I have this folder:

```
$HOME/folder_a -|
               - folder_b -|
                          - executable_1
                          - ordinary_file
               -folder_c  -|
                           - executable_2
                           - another_ordinary_file
```

And I have this same structure and files of `folder_a` into another place (`$external_driver/folder_a`)

What is my problem: The executable (`chmod +x`) files on my `$HOME/folder_a` are not executable in my $external_driver/...

But I can't override this files. They are different in content, but have exactly same names.

Does anyone can help me build a shell script to locate all this executable files, and using the same path, apply the `chmod +x` to the same filename on my $external_driver ?

Really thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:

Final solution on the answer.

Comment: You gotta show a bit of good faith and at least _attempt_ to script this yourself. We're not here to do your work for you :)

Comment: I said to help me because I have no clue to even start this devil-script. But I'm right trying to do it. Thanks @Marvin

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it...

```
cd $HOME/folder_a
find . -executable | sed 's/^./\/Path\/To\/Other\/Dir/'
```

Check the output. If correct change it to

```
cd $HOME/folder_a
find . -executable | sed 's/^./\/Path\/To\/Other\/Dir/' | xargs chmod +x
```

Comment: Thanks @amit_g, I'll use this trick with sed and xargs on the final solution. Have already updated my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Could finally find a solution with this:

```
for exec_file in $(find . -type f -executable); do 
    echo $exec_file | sed 's/^./..\/test2/' | xargs chmod +x; 
  fi; 
done
```

Thanks again, @Marvin and @amit_g !

Comment: You don't have to check for the dir but if you do want to, you can filter it in the find itself. Use find - type f.